# Possible Recursion issue, event conflict: Can't set .droppable() and .draggable() to the same selector, 

Tags: jquery

so I have found that when I add both `.draggable()` and `.droppable()` to an element. (in this case, an image) that it won't work.  The `.droppable().over:` code never fires.

it is probably due to some recursion I use to move my images, but I can't figure out why its breaking.

I have found out whats broken, and split out the problem domain into a .jsFiddle

I'm thinking I have some kind of event conflict going on with setting the .droppable() code.  It can be 'fixed' by commenting out the 'over' event in the top `.droppable()`

**well I *need* that 'over' event to do some work**, hence, my problem.

in the code in the fiddle, you see 2 pawns on some chess squares.  hovering one pawn over another should make an alert pop up, but only works when you comment out the "over" event in the  top (spot)  droppable:

http://jsfiddle.net/KevinGabbert/jBQby/60/

Success means that you pick up one pawn, and hover it over the other. an alert will pop up telling you the ID of the pawn being hovered OVER. (I already have a workaround, but I need to know why the 'over' event isn't working, and how to structure my code to make it work)

**I am not looking for a workaround.  I am looking to for the answer that makes the 'over' code work**

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in your code? I thought it's possible to use both droppable and draggable: http://jsfiddle.net/5k7Aa/

Comment: very possible.  I'll do a bit more research on this on first.  Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: ok. I've clarified the problem.  apparently I'm having an event conflict but I can't tell why.  whatever the case, when you comment out an event mapping (shown in the fiddle ref'd above), things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your selectors. You should use

```
board.AddDragAndDrop(".piece", ".thing")
```

When you make the piece droppable it accepts class "ui-droppable" and when you make after that the spot droppable it actually match the pieces because they already have "ui-droppable" class. Your alert on the top is working because you are overriding "droppable" on the pieces. Hope this helps and sorry for my bad english ;)

**Edit:**
when you are calling

```
_newPiece.AddPieceEvents(dragSelector);
```

jQueryUI add class **ui-droppable** on all pieces and after that you are calling

```
_newSpot.AddSpotEvents(dropSelector);
```

the pieces already have class **ui-droppable** and you are initializing droppable on them again

Comment: I corrected your entry, but you had the right idea.  Congratulations.

its because I am adding ui-droppable twice, and the spot ui-droppable is overriding the piece ui-droppable

Comment: however.. the selectors don't really add into the equation, its in the events, like you said.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the order of what events you bind, both events will fire. I didn't check why.

So instead of doing

```
    _newPiece.AddPieceEvents(dragSelector);
    _newSpot.AddSpotEvents(dropSelector);
```

you switch to

```
    _newSpot.AddSpotEvents(dropSelector);
    _newPiece.AddPieceEvents(dragSelector);
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siniec/jBQby/61/)

Comment: are you kidding me? OMFG.  if no one can come up with why, then the prize is yours.

Comment: your "updated .jsFiddle" doesn't work. but I did what you said here, and it does:  http://jsfiddle.net/KevinGabbert/jBQby/62/

Comment: Ah, yea, i used console.log instead of alert. alert gives me nightmares ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works for retrieving the id of the image:

```
AddSpotEvents: function(dropSelector) {

    $(dropSelector).droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) { 
            var pieceId = $(this).children("img").get(0).id;
            var draggedPiece = ui.draggable.get(0);
            var thisId = draggedPiece.id;
            if ((pieceId != "undefined")&&(pieceId!=thisId))
                alert(pieceId + " " + thisId);
        },
```

Also change second function

```
AddPieceEvents: function(dragSelector) {

    $(dragSelector).draggable({
        drag: function(event, ui) {

            var helper = ui.helper;
            var helperID = helper.attr('id'); //data
            _draggedPieceID = helperID; //cheat.  this data needs to be stored elsewhere

        }
    });
    $(dragSelector).droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
            alert("HI");//$(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know the 'over' event will work normally, but in my example in the jsFiddle, the over event does not fire, rendering this code useless.

Comment: I have it firing everytime for me with your code. I also changed your AddPieceEvent but I don't get that over event to fire.